# VBA Copy and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a VBA that is suppose to copy the on the **`"data"`** sheet and paste it on the **`"Internal Use"`** via searching a cell on cell in the **`"Internal Use"`**  I'm not getting an error it is just not doing it and it after I run the macro it just stays on the "data" sheet.

What am I missing?

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Worksheets("Internal Use").Activate
project = Range("C4")
Worksheets("data").Activate
nr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Row = 2 To nr
If Range("F" & Row) = Worksheets("Internal Use").Range("C4") Then
Range("Q" & Row) = Worksheets("Internal Use").Range("C7")
End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're trying to do. Let me know if this is what you want.

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim nr As Long
Dim project As Variant

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Internal Use")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("data")
project = ws1.Range("C4").Value2

With ws1
    nr = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = 2 To nr
        If .Range("F" & r) = project Then
            ws2.Range("Q" & r) = .Range("C7")
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ricardo,

Your code is working fine. Question is what are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to paste on 'Internal Use' sheet, you need to activate it. I have added a line to activate it. Please be more specific on what you want to accomplish.

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Worksheets("Internal Use").Activate
project = Range("C4")
Worksheets("data").Activate
nr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Internal Use").Activate
For Row = 2 To nr
If Range("F" & Row) = Worksheets("Internal Use").Range("C4") Then
Range("Q" & Row) = Worksheets("Internal Use").Range("C7")
End If

Next Row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to populate column Q on the data sheet with the value from Worksheet Internal Use cell C7, whenever column F on the same row is equal to cell C4.
I have to say that that's easily solvable with a formula using index match or a conditional formula like `=If(F2='Internal Use'!$C$4,'Internal Use'!$C$7,"")` (Just paste in column F). At least this is what your code currently more or less does or seems to want to achieve.

That said let's take a look at your code:
First of all avoid `.Activate`, it's unnecessary overhead. This will activate the worksheet. (By the way, the last `.activate` you use, is on the data worksheet, hence it stays there) Next you store C4 in an undeclared variable called project that you never use. 
Next you reference the cells everywhere in the loop again. This means there is huge overhead on accessing and reading out these cells. Lastly you do this in a loop; I assume this is to avoid filling up any of the other rows.

To make your code work, you could use:

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim project as string
Dim writeValue as string
Dim lr as long
Dim wr as long

project = Worksheets("Internal Use").Range("C4").value
writeValue = Worksheets("data").Range("C7").value

lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Worksheets("data")
    For wr = 2 To lr
        If .Range("F" & wr).value = project Then
            .Range("Q" & rw).value = writeValue
        End If
    Next wr
End With
End Sub
```

This will do the trick.

Neater would be to avoid the for loop and testing all cells. Two options are putting the entire F and Q columns into arrays and loop through those simultaniously  while altering the Q-array before dumping the values back in the sheet, or use a Find-algorithm such as Chip Pearons FindAll: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/findall.aspx